# How can I find the DELL Service Tag for my VMware ESXi host using PowerCLI?

Tags: powershell, vmware, host, esxi

Need powershell cli command to find DELL Service Tag for Server/Host(NOT SERIAL NUMBER, OR LAPTOP, DESKTOP OR VIRTUAL MACHINE) in VMware 6.7. I can find it in the gui; but in powershell cli it is very illusive.
I Would to add this to a script for weekly reporting...

gwmi win32_bios - gives a serial number instead of service tag

get-vmhost -name vmhostesxi01 | fl  - none of the properties were successful

Comment: https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-PowerCLI-Discussions/get-service-tag-of-ESX-Server/td-p/2433039

Comment: This article helped.
I did get the the Service Tag using this command.
 - (Get-VMHost -name <ESXIHOST> |Get-View).Hardware.SystemInfo| select SerialNumber    "VMWare will display the Tag as a Serial Number" . which is good, however It does not give me the host name? Trying the same command with"Select Name" leaves the Name field blank.  How do I structure the command to get basic host info plus the the service tag?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the DELL Service Tag for a Dell server/host in VMware 6.7 using PowerShell, you can use the following command:

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_BIOS -Namespace "root\CIMv2" -ComputerName "hostname").SerialNumber
```

Replace **"hostname"** with the actual hostname or IP address of the server/host you want to query. This command uses the Get-WmiObject cmdlet to query the Win32_BIOS class and retrieve the SerialNumber property, which contains the DELL Service Tag.

Make sure you have the appropriate permissions and access to the server/host you are querying.